# all combination of two columns from a table

Tags: sql

I have a table like this

```
date        |job|score
----------------------
04-01-2020  |j1 |123
04-01-2020  |j2 |524
04-01-2020  |j3 |323
04-02-2020  |j1 |533
04-02-2020  |j2 |242
04-03-2020  |j1 |432
04-03-2020  |j2 |732
04-03-2020  |j3 |932
```

If you look at the table job j3 does not have an entry for 4/2/2020.

What I am looking for is

```
date        |job|score
----------------------
04-01-2020  |j1 |123
04-01-2020  |j2 |524
04-01-2020  |j3 |323
04-02-2020  |j1 |533
04-02-2020  |j2 |242
04-02-2020  |j3 |null <---- This is what I am trying to get
04-03-2020  |j1 |432
04-03-2020  |j2 |732
04-03-2020  |j3 |932
```

I want all the possible combination of the date and job along with the score. If the score is not there then a null. I am trying some cross join but to no luck.

Comment: how you can give these results? please write you query, write your tried and plan of data... we cant help you by this model of ask question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `cross join` to generate the rows and then a `left join` to bring in existing values:

```
select d.date, j.job, t.score
from (select distinct date from t) d cross join
     (select distinct job from t) j left join
     t
     on t.date = d.date and t.job = j.job;
```